# How can I clip a blur UIVisualEffectView with a PNG mask?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uiblureffect

I have a blurred UIVisualEffectView and would like to mask it with a PNG UIImage.

I have this code for now, but if I apply the mask, the view doesn't apply the blur effect anymore.

```
let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
maskLayer.contents = UIImage(named: "botnavbarmask")?.cgImage

let maskView = UIView(frame: self.view.frame)
maskView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
maskView.layer.mask = maskLayer

blurBottom.mask = maskView
```

Is it even possible to apply a mask to the blur effect?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

here it is:

```
let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .light))
let logoView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "logo"))
blurView.mask = logoView
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below lines of code,

```
let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
maskLayer.contents = UIImage(named: "icono-menu")?.cgImage

maskLayer.frame = self.blurBottom.bounds
self.blurBottom.layer.masksToBounds = true
self.blurBottom.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Doesn't work. The view is masked but the blur effect isn't applied.

Comment: I'll try to prepare a minimal example to show the "bug".

Comment: @CarloVespa please post an example and i will try to help you again

Comment: No, we decided to simplify the design and not use a masked blur, at least for the time being. I will try to send you an example anyways, because we are probably going to need it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

`UIVisualEffectView` is kinda wonky. What if you take a snapshot of your effectview, then apply the mask?

```
func imageFromView(_ view: UIView) -> UIImage {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.frame.size, false, 0.0)
    view.drawHierarchy(in: view.frame, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    let snapshotImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return snapshotImage
}
```

I half expect the effectview not to show up, but might be worth a try.